# Ruby Base64 encode include linebreaks in variable

Tags: ruby, variables, base64

### base64 encode with line returns

in an attempt to understand how to append line returns in Base64 through the [Base64 module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html), i'm having trouble getting the encoding to do what I want...

simply put, given my bad code:

```
require "base64"
#
enc   = Base64.encode64(%q[
    #!/bin/bash
    echo 'this is a test of nesting quotes using ruby's %q thing-a-ma-bob'
    echo 'this should return a base64 formattes version of this "file" for the purposes of cloudconfig formation'
    echo "i'm not quite certain what this script should do... so for now it does a lot of nothing ... and i don't care"
    df -h |awk '{print $1"[ ]"$2"{ }"$3" -- "$4}'
    ])
#
plain = Base64.decode64(enc)
#
#
puts "base64: "+enc
puts
puts "plain:"
puts plain
puts
puts "let's run the script now for testing:"
puts
exec({"code" => plain}, "echo ; echo bash ; echo $code")
```

### returns:

```
base64: CiAgICAjIS9iaW4vYmFzaAogICAgZWNobyAndGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qgb2Yg
bmVzdGluZyBxdW90ZXMgdXNpbmcgcnVieSdzICVxIHRoaW5nLWEtbWEtYm9i
JwogICAgZWNobyAndGhpcyBzaG91bGQgcmV0dXJuIGEgYmFzZTY0IGZvcm1h
dHRlcyB2ZXJzaW9uIG9mIHRoaXMgImZpbGUiIGZvciB0aGUgcHVycG9zZXMg
b2YgY2xvdWRjb25maWcgZm9ybWF0aW9uJwogICAgZWNobyAiaSdtIG5vdCBx
dWl0ZSBjZXJ0YWluIHdoYXQgdGhpcyBzY3JpcHQgc2hvdWxkIGRvLi4uIHNv
IGZvciBub3cgaXQgZG9lcyBhIGxvdCBvZiBub3RoaW5nIC4uLiBhbmQgaSBk
b24ndCBjYXJlIgogICAgZGYgLWggfGF3ayAne3ByaW50ICQxIlsgXSIkMiJ7
IH0iJDMiIC0tICIkNH0nCiAgICA=

plain:

#!/bin/bash
echo 'this is a test of nesting quotes using ruby's %q thing-a-ma-bob'
echo 'this should return a base64 formattes version of this "file" for the purposes of cloudconfig formation'
echo "i'm not quite certain what this script should do... so for now it does a lot of nothing ... and i don't care"
df -h |awk '{print $1"[ ]"$2"{ }"$3" -- "$4}'


let's run the script now for testing:


bash
#!/bin/bash echo 'this is a test of nesting quotes using ruby's %q thing-a-ma-bob' echo 'this should return a base64 formattes version of this "file" for the purposes of cloudconfig formation' echo "i'm not quite certain what this script should do... so for now it does a lot of nothing ... and i don't care" df -h |awk '{print $1"[ ]"$2"{ }"$3" -- "$4}'
```

### I would like to try to understand

how to have the line-breaks carry into the variable I'm passing into the system command, with out having to format as follows:

```
plain = 'VGhpcyBpcyBsaW5lIG9uZQpUaGlzIG' +
    'lzIGxpbmUgdHdvClRoaXMgaXMgbGlu' +
    'ZSB0aHJlZQpBbmQgc28gb24uLi4K'
```

### thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to with how `echo` handles its inputs, it is not related to the base 64 encoding / decoding.

You call to `exec` has `echo $code`. Here `$code` is expanded and then is split on whitespace before being passed to `echo` as a list of strings. `echo` then prints out each one separated by spaces.

To prevent this you can make sure the entire `$code` variable is passed directly as a single string by enclosing it in quotes. Change your `exec` line to (note the extra quotes around `$code`):

```
exec({"code" => plain}, "echo ; echo bash ; echo \"$code\"")
```

This will print the block out including the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

When you encode your payload, you may need to include the newline characters before encoding via Base64. Please see below:

```
[7] pry(main)> require "base64"
=> true
[8] pry(main)> Base64.encode64("Apple\nBacon")
=> "QXBwbGUKQmFjb24=\n"
[9] pry(main)> Base64.decode64(_)
=> "Apple\nBacon"
[10] pry(main)> Base64.encode64("Apple\nBacon")
=> "QXBwbGUKQmFjb24=\n"
[11] pry(main)> puts Base64.decode64(_)
Apple
Bacon
```

By placing the "\n" in the string before encoding, it will be returned when decoding and subsequently printed as well

Comment: is there a way to specify some sort of join character?  I appreciate your response, but the goal is to keep the code entered into the string as natural as possible.

Comment: the odd thing, is the line returns show when i decode by simply include a new line in the script i'm encoding... it's just when i call it in the systm/exec/etc function that it loses that line return.